# Finding area using Riemann sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When finding area using Riemann sum, how I can know how many rectangles should I have to use?  is there any way of finding the number of rectangles?

Comment: In general the more rectangles you use, the more accurate ill be the answer.  So it depends on the accuracy requirement for the given problem/

Comment: I believe that when we approximate the area under a curve to be the sum of areas of $n$ rectangles under the curve, we consider that $n \to \infty$. So one answer to your question is that we're using infinitely many rectangles to find the area.

Answer (score 1):

To find a $n$-th Riemann sum you use $n$ rectangles. A $n$-th Riemann sum just approximates the (net) area under the graph of your function. And if $n$ is big, then your approximation is better. To actually compute the "exact" area under the graph of your function, then you take the limit of $n$-th Riemann sums as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You generally find the area by starting out with $n$ rectangles, of width $\dfrac {b-a}n$, say, and then letting $n\to\infty$.  So, in the limit,  you wind up with infinitely many rectangles of infinitesimal width.

That is, the actual area under the curve $y=f(x)$ between $a$ and $b$, is a limit of finite Riemann sums.

So we have $A=\int_a^b f(x)\operatorname{dx}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n f(x_k^*)(x_{k+1}-x_k)$, where $x_0,\dots,x_n$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, and $x_k^*\in [x_k,x_{k+1}]$.  For instance, we could let $x_k=a+k(\dfrac{b-a}n)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one answer for this question. More is almost always better, but there can be the slight worry of having to do larger calculations. That’s usually not an issue, though, so I would just recommend using many rectangles in all cases.